# Is there any way by which I can insert an item between a listview.builder in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of 10 items that I am displaying with a listview.builder. I want to display an item in between the listview after suppose 3 items in the list, how can I do that?

Comment: you can use `List.insert` - i assume you have some `List` with your data, right?

Comment: Yes, my data is in a list. But the element I want to display in middle of the listview, it is not needed to be added to the main list. I am stuck in how to do that.

Comment: so you have two lists? main list and ...?

Comment: The List that I am displaying with the listview.builder is the main list, it has few items. The builder will build the list according to the length of the list. I just want to show an element between the listview, that element is not a part of the list. Like for example an advertisement between a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. there is a builder called Listview.separated()

```
 ListView.separated(
          itemCount: 10,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => const ListTile(),
          separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
            if (index == 3) {
              // add widget after three item
              return Container();
            }
            return const SizedBox.shrink();
          },
        ),
```

Comment: This will add the widget after every 3 items, right? If it does that then it is not exactly the solution, that widget needs to be displayed only once, after the first 3 item only. Please help if there's a way.

Comment: yes you can do it, just change the separator condition with if(index == 3){}

Answer (score 0):

Building on Sanjay's answer, this should add it in the middle of the list without affecting the list

```
var list = [val1, val2, val3, ..];

ListView.separated(
      itemCount: list.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => const ListTile(),
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
        // For even list length case
        if (list.length % 2 == 0 && index == list.length/2) {
          return YourSeparator();
        } 
        // For odd list length case (if you want it before the middle item then 
        // change to floor())
        else if (list.length % 2 == 1 && index == (list.length/2).ceil() ) {
          return YourSeparator();
        } else {
          return SizedBox();
        }
      },
    ),
```